# How can I use `jq` to find common values from two string arrays

Tags: jq

I have two string arrays and I'd like to find all strings from the second array that exist in the first array. For example:

```
arr1=["a", "b", "c"]
arr2=["b", "d", "1"]
```

I'd like to return `["b"]`.

I found some subtraction like:

```
> jq --null-input '["a", "b", "c"] - ["b", "d", "1"]'
[
  "a",
  "c"
]
```

but it removes the matched value. How can I get the opposite result?

Comment: Subtract this result from `arr1`.

Comment: but it will return `1` in the result which I don't want

Comment: `jq -n --argjson arr1 '["a","b","c"]' --argjson arr2 '["b","d","1"]' '$arr1 - ($arr1 - $arr2)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do

```
MATCH - (MATCH - COMPARE)
```

So in your case:

```
["a", "b", "c"] - (["a", "b", "c"] - ["b", "d", "1"])
```

Will output

```json
[
  "b"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

A more verbose method: count all the entries and keep the ones with count == 2

```bash
jq -n --argjson arr1 '["a","b","c"]' --argjson arr2 '["b","d","1"]' '
    $arr1 + $arr2 
    | reduce .[] as $x ({}; .[$x] += 1) 
    | to_entries 
    | map(select(.value == 2) | .key)
'
```